# getting several elements by tag name and checking elements tag in a loop echoing it

Tags: php, dom

This is code sample that works

```
$doc->loadHTML($article_header);
$imgs = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');
foreach ($imgs as $img) {
```

`$imgs` takes from `$doc` elements with tag name `img` and then I do some operations.

Now I want to getElementsByTagName > img OR iframe and then using $img check which element is this and echo if it is iframe or img.

Please modify my code if it is possible.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use XPath on your DOMDocument as follows:

```
$doc->loadHTML($article_header);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);

$imagesAndIframes = $xpath->query('//img | //iframe');

$length = $imagesAndIframes->length;
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
    $element = $imagesAndIframes->item($i);

    if ($element->tagName == 'img') {
        echo 'img';
    } else {
        echo 'iframe';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use the following way, because by using this code, you will not get any error if there is no "`iframe`" / "`img`" tag present in the object "`$doc`" (as you are perfectly checking the existence of any elements using the "`count()`" function):-

```
$doc->loadHTML($article_header);
$imgs = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');
$iframes = $doc->getElementsByTagName('iframe');

if (count($imgs)) {
    foreach ($imgs as $img) {
        // Do some logic on "img" tag
    }
}

if (count($iframes)) {
    foreach ($iframes as $iframe) {
        // Do some logic on "iframe" tag
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: sorry but I'm asking for little bit different thing

Comment: So what are you asking if not this?

Comment: Knowledge Craving separated imgs from iframes and I don't like this.  Your approach  Jan-Henk  I think is better for me so I choose it