# Finding multiple elements by tag name using the PHP XML DOM parser

Tags: php, xml, dom, getelementsbytagname

I can get all image elements in the DOM like this:

```
$element->getElementsByTagName('img')
```

How can I get all image and iframe elements in the DOM in one request? Something like:

```
$element->getElementsByTagName('img, iframe')
```

Comment: This might help!
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7906581/getting-several-elements-by-tag-name-and-checking-elements-tag-in-a-loop-echoing

Comment: @algoriyhtsmts Thanks for the help. That's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `getElementsByTagName` you cannot get multiple elements by tag name. You can get one tag at a time only. To achieve this, there are two ways

> Calling Tag for two times

```
$element->getElementsByTagName('img')
$element->getElementsByTagName('iframe')
```

OR

> Using JavaScript

document.querySelectorAll('img,ifame')

PS: I would not recommend using PHP for DOM parsing because that will impact page performance.

Hope this helps