# php - Query a table with DOMXPath

Tags: php, domxpath

I try to access the values ​​of a table on a web page with a `php` expression [DOMXPath::query](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php). When I navigate with my web browser in this page I can see this table but when I execute my query this table isn't visible and don't seem accessible.

This table have an id, but when I specify it on my query an other one is returned. I want to read the table with the id 'totals', but I only have that one with the id 'per_game'. When I inspect page's code, a lot of elements seem to be in comments.

Here is my script:

```
<?php
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$doc->strictErrorChecking = false;
$doc->recover = true;
$doc->loadHTMLFile('https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/j/jokicni01.html');
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$table = $xpath->query("//div[@id='totals']")->item(0);
$elem = $doc->saveXML($table);
echo $elem;
?>
```

How can i read elements in the table with the id 'totals' ?

The full path is `/html/body/div[@id="wrap"]/div[@id="content"]/div[@id="all_totals"]/div[@class="table_outer_container"]/div[@id="div_totals"]/table[@id="totals"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cut your query in two parts : first, retrieve the comment in the correct div, then create a new document with this content to retrieve the element you want :

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$doc->strictErrorChecking = false;
$doc->recover = true;
@$doc->loadHTMLFile('https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/j/jokicni01.html');
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

// retrieve the comment section in 'all_totals' div
$all_totals_element = $xpath->query('/html/body/div[@id="wrap"]/div[@id="content"]/div[@id="all_totals"]/comment()')->item(0);
$all_totals_table = $doc->saveXML($all_totals_element);

// strip comment tags to keep the content inside
$all_totals_table = substr($all_totals_table, strpos($all_totals_table, '<!--') + strlen('<!--'));
$all_totals_table = substr($all_totals_table, 0, strpos($all_totals_table, '-->'));

// create a new Document with the content of the comment
$tableDoc = new DOMDocument ;
$tableDoc->loadHTML($all_totals_table);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($tableDoc);

// second part of the query
$totals = $xpath->query('/div[@class="table_outer_container"]/div[@id="div_totals"]/table[@id="totals"]')->item(0);

echo $tableDoc->saveXML($totals) ;
```

Comment: Great. I see you're using `loadHTML` instead of `loadXML`, wich is a much better way.

Comment: To complete my question, if I want to read only the last line of the table (Carrer), can I had `/tfoot/tr` to the query ? Like this `$totals = $xpath->query('/div[@class="table_outer_container"]/div[@id="div_totals"]/table[@id="totals"]/tfoot/tr')->item(0);`

Comment: Just an update to my previous answer, thanks to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7906581/getting-several-elements-by-tag-name-and-checking-elements-tag-in-a-loop-echoing), I found this way `$totals = $xpath->query('/div[@class="table_outer_container"]/div[@id="div_totals"]/table[@id="totals"] | //tfoot')->item(0);`